# Optical system for cloning an image of a light source?

Tags: optics, reflection

I need to create an optical system for cloning an image of a light source to human eyes. Is there a correct solution(design) for this problem.

- Reflectivity of the mirrors must be equal. Because light that coming from the real world must be on the same brightness level for both eyes.
- Reflectivity percentage should be within the acceptable range for human eye(not less then 5%, not like in the graphic).
- Both images must be identical.

Here is my basic design(as an explanation) with full of mistakes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: 50:50 beam splitter and a 45 degrees mirror will do it.

Comment: @boyfarrel There must be a beam splitter for right eye also. Because 45 degrees mirror will not let to pass through the light that coming from front(real world). Both eyes must get exact amount of light beams and identical image.

Comment: Seriously you can do this with just the two components I said. Think about it. I can't draw a diagram right now.

Comment: Actually if you need to preserve the divergence then it's easier with a second mirror.

Comment: Could you please draw the diagram as the answer when you are available. Because I don't understand your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This system is actually a little more complicated that I first thought because the path length to both eyes must be the same to "clone" the light source.

[image: Cloning system]

Comment: Mirror 2 and Mirror 3 will block the view of eyes. Solution should use translucent(semi-transparent) mirrors so how could it be possible? I actually mentioned about this in first condition. But I didn't insist translucent mirrors, because solution could be a different design.

Comment: I don't think you understand. Mirror 2 and 3 reflect light towards both eyes!

Comment: But eyes will not see the behind of Mirror 2 and 3?

Comment: Can I use beam splitters as Mirror 2 and 3? I think yes. If your answer is yes. It is the solution. So I will accept your solution and I will be very thankful, Sir.

Comment: This already does what you want (3 criteria in your question). I don't understand what you are talking about!